# Error creating bean with name 'defaultKieStatelessSession'

Tags: grails, amazon-ec2, drools

The following error I am getting when deploying the application on AWS. This is working fine when the application is deployed on in house tomcat server. The location of path where it is unable to get byte contains file with proper read permisson. I am using grails drools 1.1.1 plugin with tomcat 7 and grails 2.4.4
Any help will be appreciated.

ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'defaultKieStatelessSession': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'defaultKieBase' while setting bean property 'kBase'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultKieBase': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get bytes for: /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/ScaffoldingGrailsPlugin$_closure2.class
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultKieStatelessSession': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'defaultKieBase' while setting bean property 'kBase'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultKieBase': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get bytes for: /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/ScaffoldingGrailsPlugin$_closure2.class
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:473)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultKieBase': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get bytes for: /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/ScaffoldingGrailsPlugin$_closure2.class
        ... 5 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using grails drools plugin, used directly drools package through maven, which took care of this issue.